# Add a new JSON Data on Tableview when it was scrolled in ios

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

i make an application that use JSON data from web services.and also in my web services contain three page.when i add a data into tableview then it fill first page data when i scroll table view then it fill second page data but first page data was removed i want keep both page data. in the tableview i want to make a load more listview like as an android. please give me solution.i post my code here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    pageNum=0;
    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/news.php?page=%d",pageNum]];
    NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    self.imagesa=[json objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imagesa);
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
    [self.table reloadData];
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    self.imagesa=[json objectForKey:@"data"];
    [self.table reloadData];
    NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imagesa);
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.imagesa.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"Cell";
    CustumCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSString *img2=[dict valueForKey:@"post_image"];
    [cell.photoimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[img2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Hisoka.jpg"] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"downloaded");

        });
    }];
    NSString *name=[dict valueForKey:@"post_title"];
    cell.namelabel.text=name;
    NSString *des=[dict valueForKey:@"post_content"];
    cell.deslabel.text=des;


    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *date=[dict valueForKey:@"post_date"];
    NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-MMM-YYYY"];
    NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];
    NSLog(@"Date %@",dateFormatted);
    cell.datelabel.text=dateFormatted;

    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
    self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
    return cell;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageNum=pageNum+1;
    NSLog(@"Page NUmber %d",pageNum);
    [self getData];
}

-(void)getData {
    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/news.php?page=%d",pageNum]];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        jdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:jdata waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

Please give me solution as possible.

Comment: `[self.imagesa addObjectsFromArray:[json objectForKey:@"data"]]` in place of `self.imagesa=[json objectForKey:@"data"];` in `-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata` method. make sure your `imagesa` array should be NSMutableArray.

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add objects in your array you are replacing your array. that's why you didnt get all data.

in viewDidLoad

```
self.imagesa = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

when you get response

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
     //check your response is NSArray class
     if ([[json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // now add your array objects in main array and then reload table.
    NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[json objectForKey:@"data"];
    [self.imagesa addObjectsFromArray:arr];
    [self.table reloadData];
    NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imagesa);
    }
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @Chintu thnx bro it was working and sorry for late reply

Comment: but i want to put a button not a scroll for load more array data

Comment: and application was crashed when third page data was loaded give me solution please

Comment: @AshishGabani you can add button in last cell and when it press call service. return cell count = arraycount + 1. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` match indexpath.row == arraycount then add button in your cell.

Comment: @Chintu i not understand what you say please can you give me code for that?

Comment: @AshishGabani check this link (http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/02/dynamically-loading-new-rows-into-a-table.html) add your button in place of load more title.

Comment: and one issue is that bro when i scroll then i get second and third page data both but i want only second page data and when second page data arrive and then scroll then i want to show third page data.

Comment: i've already answered your question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397312/load-more-table-view-in-ios) . you have to replace your `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method with my answer.

Comment: it was added but it shows full page data not single page bro.

Comment: @Chintu How we can end scroll when new data was not available?

Comment: @AshishGabani you have to add message for "no more records" in  server side. so once you get that do not call service.

Comment: but how can add a message on server side?not any solution in over side?